# Slow Performance caused by Correlated Sub-queries & Clustered Index Seek

Tags: sql-server, performance, optimization

I'm running a query in which one of the tables (FIELDDATA) has nearly 400,000 records which is taking more than 2 minutes to execute. I ran the execution plan, and noticed that the clustered seek index is hogging nearly all the time. I also ran the Database Engine Tuning Advisor to see if I could improve the performance in any way. However, it only suggested a 3% improvement. Neither does the SQL management windows throws a 'missing index' suggestion. How do I optimize this query? I understand this is because of the correlated subqueries. Any pointers on how should I re-write the query would help immensely.

Clustered Index on FIELDDATA(on keys ID, FIELDID, tableRow and TableCol).
Non-Clustered Indices on FIELDDATA are (all non-unique) (a. FIELDID, b. NVALUE, c. SVALUE) .

```
SELECT E.EVENTID "EVENTID",E.STEPCOUNT "STEPCOUNT",E.STATUSMODIFIED "STATUSMODIFIED",
    F.FORMID "FORMID",E.SUBJECT "SUBJECT",E.COPY "COPY",T.TRACKERID "DFS__TrackerID",
    CASE WHEN E.EVENTTYPE=5 OR F.FORMTYPE='fp' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END "ALLOWOPEN",

    (SELECT SVALUE FROM FIELDDATA WHERE ID=E.EVENTID AND FIELDID='AdminEmail') "ADMINEMAIL",
    (SELECT SVALUE FROM FIELDDATA WHERE ID=E.EVENTID AND FIELDID='ProcessID') "PROCESSID",
    (SELECT SVALUE FROM FIELDDATA WHERE ID=E.EVENTID AND FIELDID='NotificationType') "NOTIFICATIONTYPE",
    (SELECT SVALUE FROM FIELDDATA WHERE ID=E.EVENTID AND FIELDID='NotificationID') "NOTIFICATIONID",
    (SELECT SVALUE FROM FIELDDATA WHERE ID=E.EVENTID AND FIELDID='SCUserID') "SCUSERID",
    (SELECT SVALUE FROM FIELDDATA WHERE ID=E.EVENTID AND FIELDID='DueDate') "DUEDATE" 

FROM  EVENTS    E WITH (NOLOCK), 
    (SELECT EVENTID, EVENTDEFID, STATUS FROM EVENTS WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE EVENTTYPE<>6) E1, 
     FORMS     F1 WITH (NOLOCK), FORMS     F WITH (NOLOCK), ROUTEDEF  D WITH (NOLOCK), 
     TRACKER   T WITH (NOLOCK), CONTAINERS C WITH (NOLOCK)  

WHERE (T.SENDER=@P0 OR (E.OWNER=LOWER(@P1) AND 

    (EXISTS (SELECT ID FROM FIELDDATA WHERE E.EVENTID=ID AND ((TABLECOL='isCC' OR FIELDID='isCC') AND SVALUE = 'true')))))
     AND (E.EVENTTYPE=1 OR E.EVENTTYPE=4 OR E.EVENTTYPE=6 OR E.EVENTTYPE=5) 
     AND ((T.ACTION>=1 AND T.ACTION<7) OR T.ACTION=10 OR T.ACTION=11 OR T.ACTION=4000 OR T.ACTION=4001 OR T.ACTION=4003 OR T.ACTION=4004) 
     AND E.EVENTDEFID=F.FORMREV AND E1.EVENTID=E.EVENTID AND E1.EVENTDEFID=F1.FORMREV AND D.FORMGUID=F1.FORMGUID AND T.TASKID=E.TASKID AND C.CONTAINERID=E.LOCATION AND 

    ((EXISTS (SELECT ID FROM FIELDDATA WHERE E.EVENTID=ID AND ((TABLECOL='NotificationID' OR FIELDID='NotificationID') AND LEN(SVALUE) > 0)))) 
    AND ((DATEADD(day,-@P2,GETDATE()) < E.STATUSMODIFIED AND E1.STATUS<>1) OR (E1.STATUS=1)) ORDER BY DUEDATE DESC
```

Execution Plan :: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0p8mDJ5O2ztcGtjeWF6dUJTNFk/view?usp=sharing

**EDIT** :

I tried the same query in my local environment (SQL Server 2014) and noticed that the query was only taking 30 seconds. I've played with the indexes and have been able to bring down he time to 13 seconds. I can still see that the order by (sort clause) is taking 4-5 seconds time. I tried updating the statistics, however the warning is the SQL plan did not go.

Final Indexes on FIELDDATA:

1. Clustered Index on FieldID, ID, Table Row, Table Col
2. Non-Cl. Index: a)FieldId, ID including SVALUE; b)SVALUE including ID

I also tried restructuring the query, however both with and without CTE the query takes near about the same time (12-14 seconds).

Execution Plan with and without CTE are: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B0p8mDJ5O2ztflRHcTRlZlpsT25LMkpEUDd0OFRWblFnTEsxY20wN0lNU3RTMTA1VTJKTFk&usp=sharing

The new query (with CTE) is :

```
WITH FieldData_CTE (EVENT_ID, AdEmail, ProcID, NotType, NotID, UsrId, DuDate) 
AS 
(
    Select EVENTID,
    (SELECT SVALUE FROM FIELDDATA WHERE ID=E.EVENTID AND FIELDID='AdminEmail') "ADMINEMAIL",
    (SELECT SVALUE FROM FIELDDATA WHERE ID=E.EVENTID AND FIELDID='ProcessID') "PROCESSID",
    (SELECT SVALUE FROM FIELDDATA WHERE ID=E.EVENTID AND FIELDID='NotificationType') "NOTIFICATIONTYPE",
    (SELECT SVALUE FROM FIELDDATA WHERE ID=E.EVENTID AND FIELDID='NotificationID') "NOTIFICATIONID",
    (SELECT SVALUE FROM FIELDDATA WHERE ID=E.EVENTID AND FIELDID='SCUserID') "SCUSERID",
    (SELECT SVALUE FROM FIELDDATA WHERE ID=E.EVENTID AND FIELDID='DueDate') "DUEDATE"
    From Events E
)

SELECT E.EVENTID "EVENTID",E.STEPCOUNT "STEPCOUNT",E.STATUSMODIFIED "STATUSMODIFIED",
F.FORMID "FORMID",E.SUBJECT "SUBJECT",E.COPY "COPY",T.TRACKERID "DFS__TrackerID",
CASE WHEN E.EVENTTYPE=5 OR F.FORMTYPE='fp' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END "ALLOWOPEN", CTE.AdEmail "ADMINEMAIL", CTE.ProcID "PROCESSID", CTE.NotType "NOTIFICATIONTYPE", 
  CTE.NotID "NOTIFICATIONID", CTE.UsrId "SCUSERID", CTE.DuDate "DUEDATE" 

FROM  EVENTS E WITH (NOLOCK), FieldData_CTE CTE, 
    (SELECT EVENTID, EVENTDEFID, STATUS FROM EVENTS WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE EVENTTYPE<>6) E1, 
 FORMS     F1 WITH (NOLOCK), FORMS     F WITH (NOLOCK), ROUTEDEF  D WITH (NOLOCK), 
 TRACKER   T WITH (NOLOCK), CONTAINERS C WITH (NOLOCK)  

WHERE  (T.SENDER=@P0 OR (E.OWNER=LOWER(@P1) AND 

    (EXISTS (SELECT ID FROM FIELDDATA WHERE E.EVENTID=ID AND ((TABLECOL='isCC' OR FIELDID='isCC') AND SVALUE = 'true')))))
 AND (E.EVENTTYPE=1 OR E.EVENTTYPE=4 OR E.EVENTTYPE=6 OR E.EVENTTYPE=5) 
 AND ((T.ACTION>=1 AND T.ACTION<7) OR T.ACTION=10 OR T.ACTION=11 OR T.ACTION=4000 OR T.ACTION=4001 OR T.ACTION=4003 OR T.ACTION=4004) 
 AND E.EVENTDEFID=F.FORMREV AND E1.EVENTID=E.EVENTID AND E1.EVENTDEFID=F1.FORMREV AND D.FORMGUID=F1.FORMGUID AND T.TASKID=E.TASKID AND C.CONTAINERID=E.LOCATION AND 

    ((EXISTS (SELECT ID FROM FIELDDATA WHERE E.EVENTID=ID AND ((TABLECOL='NotificationID' OR FIELDID='NotificationID') AND LEN(SVALUE) > 0)))) 
AND ((DATEADD(day,-@P2,GETDATE()) < E.STATUSMODIFIED AND E1.STATUS<>1) OR (E1.STATUS=1)) AND E.EVENTID=CTE.EVENT_ID ORDER BY DUEDATE
```

I cannot create any more indices on the Events table (as suggested in the plan)

Comment: You're hitting FieldData far too many times and don't have an index suitable to accurately estimate the number of rows returned by each correlated subquery. You might want to consider an index on `FieldData(ID, FieldID)`

Comment: Try using a self join on the event table instead of the subquery in the from clause - Then you can filter on that in the where clause - and skip all the nolocks and start the query with set transaction isolation level read uncommited if you dont care about dirty reads

Comment: @MarkSinkinson : I've added the index on fieldId with covering index as id and svalue which has indeed improved the performance a bit.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the query has to retrieve 13.7 billion rows from FIELDDATA in aggregate. This is caused by two significant issues with your query. One will be easy to solve, one will be harder.

The easy problem is with the index. As one commented suggested, you need to add a nonclustered index on FIELDDATA(ID, FIELDID). The clustered index scan is pulling 5764 rows each time it's called, then filtering down to the one row it needs to return. The index should allow it to pull only one row each time it's called, reducing the total to around 2.3 million.

The larger, more difficult problem is that you're using subqueries to return column data in the SELECT clause. SQL Server processes the SELECT clause after most of the other clauses in the query. In this case, the FROM (JOIN) clause would be processed, then the WHERE clause would filter certain rows from those returned by JOIN. The SELECT clause is then applied to each of the rows returned by WHERE. In this case, that's 395,939 rows. Each subquery in the SELECT clause is run once for each row - since you have subqueries on 6 columns, you are querying FIELDDATA 2.3 million times each time your query is run.

To reduce that, you need to get those subqueries out of the SELECT clause and into something that can be joined in your FROM clause. If you're using SQL Server 2005 or later, my best suggestion would be to create a common table expression (or subquery) with a PIVOT clause to bring all of the SVALUE values for each ID into one row. If you're using an earlier version, your best bet may be to extract the FIELDDATA data into a temporary table prior to this query, again with one row per ID that contains all of the necessary SVALUE values.

Comment: Thanks for the vital statistics! I've edited the question as per your inputs. Why do we need the Pivot clause here?

Comment: To get rid of the very expensive subqueries in the SELECT. The PIVOT takes your very normalized FIELDDATA table and flattens it.  The resulting dataset has an ID column and one column per FIELDID value that has the FIELDID as the column name and the associated SVALUE value as the data. By using the PIVOT query as a CTE or as a derived table subquery, you can join it as if it was a regular table, and you can refer to the FIELDID values as column names.

Answer (score 1):

Even in your updated query, you hit `FIELDDATA` eight times and `Events` three times. Rather than focusing so much on indexes, let's refactor to reduce the number of table hits. See below for an example. This is just my best guess at a refactor without a full understanding of your data, so keep or ignore the bits that work for your data. Changes include:

- Use T-SQL's behavior where aggregates eliminate NULLs to our advantage. We hit FieldData once, and squish a big result into one line per EventID.
- Refactored the joins to use modern syntax.
- Replaced the NOLOCKS with a one-liner to set isolation level (since you had it on every table, I'm assuming you understand the implications of NOLOCK and that this syntax is equivalent)
- Moved a few other things around.
- Improved readability.

Another thing I noticed is that your Forms `F1` and ROUTEDEF `D` tables aren't used in the select anywhere. Is it possible that you don't even need to hit these tables?

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;

-- don't put functions in WHERE clauses whenever you can avoid it. Do it here in advance
SET @P1 = LOWER(@P1);
SET @P2 = DATEADD(day,-@P2,GETDATE());

WITH FieldData_CTE AS  (

    SELECT
        EVENTID,
        STEPCOUNT,
        STATUSMODIFIED,
        SUBJECT,
        COPY,
        EVENTTYPE, 
        ASDFS__TrackerID,
        ADMINEMAIL,
        PROCESSID,
        NOTIFICATIONTYPE,
        NOTIFICATIONID,
        SCUSERID,
        DUEDATE
    FROM
        (
        Select 
            EVENTID,
            E.STEPCOUNT,
            E.STATUSMODIFIED,
            E.SUBJECT,
            E.COPY,
            E.EVENTTYPE, 
            T.TRACKERID ASDFS__TrackerID,                
            CASE WHEN FIELDID='AdminEmail' THEN SVALUE ELSE NULL END AS ADMINEMAIL,
            CASE WHEN FIELDID='ProcessID' THEN SVALUE ELSE NULL END AS PROCESSID,
            CASE WHEN FIELDID='NotificationType' THEN SVALUE ELSE NULL END AS NOTIFICATIONTYPE,
            CASE WHEN FIELDID='NotificationID' THEN SVALUE ELSE NULL END AS NOTIFICATIONID,
            CASE WHEN FIELDID='SCUserID' THEN SVALUE ELSE NULL END AS SCUSERID,
            CASE WHEN FIELDID='DueDate' THEN SVALUE ELSE NULL END AS DUEDATE,
            CASE WHEN (TABLECOL='isCC' OR FIELDID='isCC') AND SVALUE = 'true' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END AS isCC,
            CASE WHEN (TABLECOL='NotificationID' OR FIELDID='NotificationID') AND LEN(SVALUE) > 0) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END AS isNotification
        FROM
            Events E
            INNER JOIN TRACKER T ON T.TASKID=E.TASKID
            INNER JOIN FIELDDATA F ON F.ID = E.EVENTID
        WHERE
            E.EVENTTYPE IN (1,4,5,6) 
            AND T.ACTION IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,10,11,4000,4001,4003,4004)
            AND (T.SENDER = @P0 OR E.OWNER = @P1)
        ) T
    GROUP BY 
        EVENTID,
        STEPCOUNT,
        STATUSMODIFIED,
        SUBJECT,
        COPY,
        EVENTTYPE, 
        ASDFS__TrackerID,
        ADMINEMAIL,
        PROCESSID,
        NOTIFICATIONTYPE,
        NOTIFICATIONID,
        SCUSERID,
        DUEDATE
)



SELECT
    E.EVENTID,
    E.STEPCOUNT,
    E.STATUSMODIFIED,
    F.FORMID,
    E.SUBJECT,
    E.COPY,
    E.EVENTTYPE, 
    E.DFS__TrackerID,
    CASE WHEN E.EVENTTYPE=5 OR F.FORMTYPE='fp' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END "ALLOWOPEN", 
    E.ADMINEMAIL,
    E.PROCESSID,
    E.NOTIFICATIONTYPE,
    E.NOTIFICATIONID,
    E.SCUSERID,
    E.DUEDATE
FROM  
    FieldData_CTE E
    INNER JOIN CONTAINERS C ON C.CONTAINERID=E.LOCATION
    INNER JOIN FORMS F ON E.EVENTDEFID=F.FORMREV
WHERE  
    E.isCC = 1
    AND E.isNotification = 1
    AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 
            FROM 
                Events E1 
                INNER JOIN FORMS F1 ON E1.EVENTDEFID=F1.FORMREV
                INNER JOIN ROUTEDEF D ON D.FORMGUID=F1.FORMGUID
            WHERE 
                E1.EVENTID=E.EVENTID 
                AND E1.EVENTTYPE <> 6 
                AND ((@P2 < E.STATUSMODIFIED AND E1.STATUS<>1) OR (E1.STATUS=1))
    )
ORDER BY DUEDATE
```